# Child's name not reflected on train ticket (Indian Railways)

Tags: tickets, online-resources, indian-railways, irctc

I booked an e-ticket with IRCTC for my family. There was a form to fill in the children's details and I gave the information about the 1-year-old child who is going with me. Once the booking was done, I'm not able to see the child's details in the e-ticket. Even though no money is charged for children and I entered their name, why wouldn't names show on the e-ticket?

Comment: did you try to talk to the company? Sending an email? What is the company? What is the country? Please, add more details.

Comment: @MarcelP. indian railways is not a company. FYI

Answer (score 8):

The ticket will not show details for children under the age of 5. Only children in the age group 5 - 11 will be shown as a child and a berth will be provided to them. No details regarding infants will appear on the reservation chart or ticket, but will only be maintained in the railway database for unforeseen incidents.